# Android layout design

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development, and I  want to make a screen in android like this:

Can any one help me in doing this:

1. ImageView (leaving space of 20px from left, right and top).
2. space.
3. TextView.
4. Space.
5. TextView1.
6. space.
7. TextView2: TextView3.
8. space.

. 
.
....

If imageView is not there the textview should come up and imageview should hide.

Comment: Linear layout with orientation: vertical

Comment: how to give space from top and left

Comment: you can use margin for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip" 
        android:src="@drawable/img"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" 
        android:text="Txt1"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" 
        android:text="Txt2"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip" 
        android:text="Txt3"/>

</LinearLayout>
```